# Remove accent color on slide of Angular Material slider

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

When I slide the `mat-slider` i shouldn't see yellow color on the slider it should stay white , how can i achieve this ?

[Stackblitz Code demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unx1jf-msljvr?file=app/slider-overview-example.css)

I am using [Material Slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview)

P.s. The solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45389498/change-default-background-color-of-md-slider-of-angular-material?rq=1) doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding following chunk of css should do it.

```css
::ng-deep .mat-slider-thumb {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-color: gray !important;
}
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unx1jf-q3wm4x